# jquery image slideshow with links per image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

i'm in search of a simple *jquery image flipper/fader*, that will cycle through a bunch of images, each of them with it's own link.

the flipper will be used like so: my client wants to display logos of his own clients in succession where *each logo will link to the respective website*.

i know this can be implemented in flash, but i (and my client) think it would be cool if it's implemented in jquery in such a way that the *outgoing links are visible to google*. i have seen some jquery plugins and code that implement galleries, but they were either too complex or too simple, anyone got a code snipplet that would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google the cycle plugin

Comment: thank you so much, but regrettably, the cycle plugin does not support links

Comment: i stand corrected, can't believe i tested this plugin and STILL posted a question to SA, should have looked harder